# how to download the document using Encrypted url in SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am not able to download the document using Download.aspx with the encrypted url like below

https://contosa.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/tura/EQL4ibXUPv9Cr8E0KAUF0XkBJm76vuQmhAgFDXXlNSXh9A?e=qUH7JL

https://unilever.sharepoint.com/sites/GlobalArchitectureRepository/_layouts/15/download.aspx?sourceurl=https://contosa.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/tura/EQL4ibXUPv9Cr8E0KAUF0XkBJm76vuQmhAgFDXXlNSXh9A?e=qUH7JL

If i use the above url document is not downloading

Should we use only Full url to download the document or is there any to download with the encrypted url?

any help would be appreciated, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in SharePoint Online to download document via URL.

- **Option 1:**

Use the format:
**https://.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=document-URL**

E.g. **https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/legal/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Legal/Documents/Compliance.pdf**

- **Option 2:**

Use "Copy link" Option to get the link to document(encrypted url) and append "&download=1"

E.g. **https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/legal/ECm5WU0-3ohOo2n8-q5GQG4Bar33Prunsg4g9QvAPu3cRQ?e=UPMiz5&download=1**
[image]

Comment: Hi Allen,
If i copied the copy link URL it would be something like below 

https://xontoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sampleSite/SampleLibrary/Sample_User%20Guide.pdf?e=TfuXAi&download=1

not like what you have mentioned above. BTW the above url is not working. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer above. Did you copy link via the button as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes i done in the same way .